# Is creating Firebase service objects an expensive operation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am asking the community if it is best to get a new instance of FirebaseAuth, FirebaseDatabase, and FirebaseStorage each time I access it, or is it best to do this globally for all fragment in onCreate of MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these objects are lightweight, and do nothing on their own. Any expensive resources (such as network connections) they need are managed by the SDK deeper down. So there is no harm creating a new instance of them in each activity.

Comment: That is what I thought, but wanted to make sure. You are on FIRE tonight man!!! Thank you for the help!